# Button is covered by another element

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, cypress

I need some help please.

I have a test where i log into a website and select a status.  When i click on the update button the modal closes and another modal opens with a update success message and an ok button and an x button.

I need to validate what the message on the modal says and that the ok button works, but its not letting because of this error

Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '<button.btn.btn-success>' to be 'visible'

This element <button.btn.btn-success> is not visible because it has CSS property: position: fixed and it's being covered by another element:

This is my code im using to

```
cy.get('.modal-body > :nth-child(3) > .col-sm-9 > .form- 
control').type('No Good Reason')
cy.get('.modal-body > :nth-child(4) > .col-sm-9 > .form- 
control').type('Testing Memo')
cy.get('.btn-primary > .ng-scope').click()
//check the update ok modal appears correctly
cy.get('#updateSuccess').find(".modal- 
title").contains('Update OK').should('exist')
cy.get('.modal-body').contains('Financial Account Status 
Change (General) was updated OK').should('exist')
```

This is the element and click action im having problems with
cy.get('#updateSuccess').find('.btn').contains('OK').should('exist').click()

This is the DOM

[image: DOM]

Thanks in advance for your help

UPDATE:  OK i was able to check the elements on the modal using the exist,  so I got a bit further.  I still cant click on the ok button as the button is covered by an element on a previous modal

Answer (score 6):

If you are sure that the user can access the button, then add the `{force:true}` option to the click.

Cypress checks for [actionability](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements#Forcing) but sometimes gets it wrong.

In such a case the force option is a back-door that allows you to continue the test without checking for actionability.

```js
cy.get('.modal-body > :nth-child(3) > .col-sm-9 > .form-control').type('No Good Reason')
cy.get('.modal-body > :nth-child(4) > .col-sm-9 > .form-control').type('Testing Memo')

cy.get('.btn-primary > .ng-scope').click({force:true})  
  
cy.get('#updateSuccess').find('.btn').should('be.visible')
cy.get('#updateSuccess').find('.btn').click()
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but i dont want to use force true as i want to check some elements on the modal i.e the message on the modal is correct.  but i cant as it is covered by something else

Comment: Unless the web app is update to not have the element cover the button, then this might be the only way to click on the button. You can instead check if the button exists within the modal and then click.

Comment: Not really true, the CSS could change the the layout so applying viewport or scroll commands could do that. But with poor quality question, this is the best answer. No idea why OP thinks they can't perform tests.